# Jquery Tooltip image height & width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this tooltip code which works as a charm but I would like to know how do I set max height & width. Here is my code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $('.hoverElement').each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $(this).tooltip({ content: '<img src="@Url.Action("ShowImage")' + '?email=' + id + '" />' });
        });
    });
</script>

foreach (var item in Model.People)
{
<a class="hoverElement" href="#" title="" id="@item.Email" >@item.Name()</a>
}
```

Comment: cant you just set it with the class ? edit- I mean class the image..!

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't help: $(this).tooltip({ content: '<img src="@Url.Action("ShowImage")' + '?email=' + id + '" />', height: '10', width: '10' });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the style inline as you create the element? Something like this:

```
content: '<img style="max-height:100px;" src="@Url.Action("ShowImage")' + '?email=' + id + '" />'
```